# Servlet Output Stream not downloading in jQuery AJAX

Tags: ajax, servlets

I have the following code

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/csv;charset=UTF-8");

    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

        String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
        String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", "prueba.csv");
        response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

        out.println("test");

        OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    }

}
```

When I call the servlet from the URL **localhost:8080/downloadServlet** it downloads a .CSV file, but when I call the servlet from $.ajax post request it doesn´t work.

Here is my $.ajax code

```
$.ajax({
    url: "downloadServlet",
    type: "post",
    data: {id: 1, pass: "123"},
    error : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

How can I use $.ajax to download a SERVLET OutputStream?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue :(